# Неактивна мышь в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text

Мышь в Sublime Text 3 не реагирует на нажатие в зоне кода, для перехода по папкам и меню всё работает, но на самом коде нет, как это можно исправить?Переустановка не помогла, и в Sublime Text 2 такая же проблема

Comment: Почистить кеш, переустановить, посмотреть настройки

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц как почистить кеш?

Comment: Гуглите...обычно в appdata(под виндой)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц не помогло(